# C# .Net OracleConnection

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I need your help for resolve issue to connect in Oracle DataBase.
I have 32bit program to connecting to oracle database (this is a cooperate program) and every computer of every host in my firm have 32bit client.
I need build simple application to connecting and....

I have problem to build connection string and connect, I have instaled Oracle Client 19c (32bit),
Oracle-Client-for-Microsoft-Tools-32-bit, and write this code:

> using System;
> using System.Data;
> using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

public class COIG
{
private string connectionString = "Data Source=1234;User Id=******;Password=******;";
private OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();

```
private void ConnectOracle()
{
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Połączony");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}

private void CloseConnection()
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    conn.Dispose();
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    COIG cog = new COIG();
    cog.ConnectOracle();
    // Do other operations with the connection if needed...
    cog.CloseConnection();
}
```

For test connectig, and i don't have solusion for issue:

> Connection request timed out

i use this connectingString

> private string connectionString = "Data Source=1234;User Id=******;Password=******;";
> private string connectionString = "User Id=*****;Password=****;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=1234)));";

any one can help my please...

Comment: Debuger is 32 bit

Comment: the problem is
Microsoft Visual Studio
Attempt to load Oracle Client libraries threw
BadlmageFormatException. This problem will occur when
running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle Client components
installed.